# While linking two python files by import command, i am facing a little problem about functions here in python

Tags: python

I want to create a basic program which squares user input numbe, and i 
    want to do this by import command only,
    So I created two python files =
      1) constant.py :
    In this, i had created a function of squaring numbers [def 
    square(numbers): ]
      2) main.py :
    while using import i want to connect my constant.py file to main.py file 
    just see the code.

All is good in my code. No errors or warnings find but when i run this 
    program then i am facing errors, unable to square the number. To stop 
    this error i used try and except command but how to resolve it.
    I am using VScode...

constant.py

```
def square(number):
  return number * number
```

main.py

```
import constant
try:
  n = input(">> ")
  print(constant.square(n))
except:
  print("")
input("Press enter to exit")
```

Comment: At first glance, the variable `n` here is a string. It should be an int/float.

Comment: Why did you add the try/except?  Remove try/except and provide the error message you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are getting an error that looks something like this:

```py
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

So when you get any input, it gets stored typically as a string. Try casting n to an integer before you run the function. Something like this should work:

```py
import constant

n = int(input(">> "))
print(constant.square(n))
```